# Debugging SSAS Timeouts

Tags: sql-server, performance, security, ssas

I have a drill-through problem apparently related to security. Users in one role are seeing timeout failures when trying to invoke a drill-through action. They have permission on the action through that role and seem to have all necessary dimension and cell security rights.

Profiler is not showing me any obvious reason this is failing. What else can I use to debug this?

If I modify the user's role membership, the action works as expected, so I'm confident this is related to security somehow.

Comment: Profiler?.......

Comment: Profiler says 'query timed out'. Unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

In my specific case, this was a result of cell security. The role did not have access to all the fields returned in the drillthrough action. I missed this because there are two very similarly-named fields and my eye did not notice. It's still odd that a security denial creates a query timeout, but at least this note is here for the next person.